# refresh div not whole page

Tags: php, spry

Here is my code:

main.php:

```
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryTabbedPanels.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="SpryAssets/SpryTabbedPanels.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div id="TabbedPanels1" class="TabbedPanels" align="left">
  <ul class="TabbedPanelsTabGroup">
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">Member Group</li>
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">Fine Group</li>
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">Department</li>
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">Member</li>
  </ul>
 <div class="TabbedPanelsContentGroup">
    <div class="TabbedPanelsContent">  <?php include 'menage member group.php'; ?></div>
    <div class="TabbedPanelsContent"> <?php include 'manage fine group.php'; ?></div>
    <div class="TabbedPanelsContent"> <?php include 'manage department group.php'; ?></div>
    <div class="TabbedPanelsContent"> <?php include 'manage member main.php'; ?></div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var TabbedPanels1 = new Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels("TabbedPanels1");
//-->
</script>
```

when I click submit button which contain in menage member main.php.the whole page will be refreshed.

Comment: StackOverflow is a website targeted at **professional software developers**.  If you are not sure about what StackOverflow is or how to behave here, please review the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  If you wish to get good answers, you **must** ask good questions. I would **strongly** suggest you read [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/1228) for hints on how to ask better questions.

Comment: @sheetal, please refrain from rolling back edits that improve the quality and formatting of your question.  I have *again* reformatted your code so that people can actually see the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Look around for AJAX tutorials and you'll find an answer. You can't do this with PHP alone as you'll also need JavaScript or a JavaScript library like jQuery. Good luck :)

Comment: @sheetal369: that's rather the point that Mario was making: that this cannot be done with PHP alone. You will need to implement a client-side, JavaScript, solution.

Answer (score 0):

Submit buttons, by design, will have the affect of refreshing the page, unless you use stuff like client side scripting to override this behaviour.

Techniques like AJAX can overcome this feature, although there is still some debate over if it really is as much an issue as it seems.

As a general comment, I'd avoid using spaces in filenames e.g. `'menage member group.php'`